# efficient way to solve such questions in arithmetic progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

> QUESTION:
>   The sum of $p$ terms of an A.P is $q$ ,and the sum of $q$ terms is $p$.Find the sum of $p+q$ terms
>   MY ATTEMPT:I know it is possible to solve this question by using the formula for the sum of n terms of an A.P and substitute q from equation 1 below into equation 2 and solve for p and q.This is a very long process and i was wondering if there is any easier way to solve these sort of problems.
>   Any help is appreciated.Thanks :)
>   $$
> \frac{p}{2} (2a+(p-1)d)=q
> $$ equation 1
>   $$
> \frac{q}{2} (2a+(q-1)d)=p
> $$ equation 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
   \frac p2 (2a+(p-1)d) &= q \\
   \frac q2 (2a+(q-1)d) &= p \\
\hline
   2a+(p-1)d &= 2\frac qp \\
   2a+(q-1)d &= 2\frac pq \\
\hline
   (p-q)d &= 2\frac qp - 2\frac pq \\
   d &= 2\frac{q^2-p^2}{(p-q)pq} \\
   d &= -2\frac{p+q}{pq} \\
\end{align}

If you don't require that $d$ be an integer, then there are an infinite number of such sequences.

If you want $d$ to be an integer. Then your choices are pretty limited.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
S_n=\ &An^2&&+Bn
&&&&\scriptsize \left(A=\frac d2; \qquad B=a-\frac d2\right)\\\\
S_p=\ &Ap^2&&+Bp&&=q\tag{1}\\
S_q=\ &Aq^2&&+Bq&&=p\tag{2}\\\\
(1)-(2):\qquad 
&\  A(p^2-q^2)&&+B(p-q)&&=q-p
&&\scriptsize (p\neq q)\\
&\ A(p+q)&&+B&&=-1\\\\
S_{p+q}=\ &A(p+q)^2 &&+B(p+q) &&=\color{red}{-(p+q)}
\end{align}$$